# 'ch5-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: npm-install

Even after installed

```
npm i @crestron/ch5-utilities-cli
```

> > ch5-cli giving below error

```
'ch5-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

as per document https://www.npmjs.com/package/@crestron/ch5-utilities-cli

Answer (score 1):

It is worked when installed globally as below

```
npm install -g @crestron/ch5-utilities-cli
```